# How to traverse a tree generated from a producer function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

The following clojure code attempts to generate a tree and traverse it:

```
(def rules [[-1 0 0 0] [1 -1 0 0] [1 1 -1 0] [1 1 1 -1]])

(def initial-state {:expected 0.0
                :total 4
                :sheets [1 1 1 1]
                :probs [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]})

(defn children-of [{total :total sheets :sheets probs :probs}]
  (for [n (range 4) :let [si (sheets n)] :when (> si 0)]
     {:expected (if (= total 1) (probs n) 0.0)
      :total (+ total (dec n))
      :sheets (vector (map + sheets (rules n)))
      :probs (vector (map #(* % (/ si total)) probs))}))

(defn all-paths [root]
  ( ?? ... ?? )

(doseq [c (all-paths initial-state)]
  (println c))
```

The `children-of` function returns a seq of 0 - 4 maps, depending on the number of non-zero values in the `:sheets` vector.

My first attempt at writing the `all-paths` function was this:

```
(defn all-paths [root]
  (lazy-seq (cons root
              (for [c (children-of root)]
                (all-paths c)))))
```

But this throws a number of `java.lang.ClassCastException`s telling me that `clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number`.

So, any ideas on how to write the `all-paths` function?

UPDATE: Stacktrace ---------------------

```
(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojur
e.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number (problem_151.clj:0)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:5820)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:221)
        at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:273)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:365)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq ca
nnot be cast to java.lang.Number
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:47)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
        at clojure.lang.Cons.next(Cons.java:39)
        at clojure.lang.RT.next(RT.java:560)
        at clojure.core$next.invoke(core.clj:61)
        at clojure.core$nthnext.invoke(core.clj:3399)
        at clojure.core$print_sequential.invoke(core_print.clj:55)
        at clojure.core$fn__4853.invoke(core_print.clj:138)
        at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:167)
        at clojure.core$pr_on.invoke(core.clj:2812)
        at clojure.core$pr.invoke(core.clj:2824)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:540)
        at clojure.core$prn.doInvoke(core.clj:2852)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:540)
        at clojure.core$println.doInvoke(core.clj:2870)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at user$eval44.invoke(problem_151.clj:21)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Nu
mber
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:47)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
        at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:450)
        at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:122)
        at user$all_paths$fn__23$iter__24__28$fn__29.invoke(problem_151.clj:17)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
        at clojure.lang.Numbers.gt(Numbers.java:198)
        at user$children_of$iter__4__8$fn__9$fn__10.invoke(problem_151.clj:9)
        at user$children_of$iter__4__8$fn__9.invoke(problem_151.clj:9)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
        ... 35 more
```

Comment: Stack trace or we're just guessing.

Comment: @amalloy - I thought I was missing some other clojurial way of doing it, and the stacktrace didn't seem very illuminating (line 0 of problem_151.clj? Really?) - but anyway, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
        at clojure.lang.Numbers.gt(Numbers.java:198)
        at user$children_of$iter__4__8$fn__9$fn__10.invoke(problem_151.clj:9)
        at user$children_of$iter__4__8$fn__9.invoke(problem_151.clj:9)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
        ... 35 more
```

The real problem is at line 9: the `>` call is expecting a number but getting a sequence.

It seems to be looking at some numbered element of the `sheets` key, so how does `sheets` get to be a lazy sequence? You're mapping `+` over a sequence and converting to a vector, right?

No, that is not what you are doing. That's the difference between `vector` and `vec`:

```
user> (let [xs [1 2 3 4] ys (repeat 10)]
        ((juxt vec vector) (map + xs)))
[[1 2 3 4] [(1 2 3 4)]]
```

That is, `(vec foo)` returns a vector representation of `foo`, while `(vector foo)` returns a one-element vector, containing `foo` itself as an element.

Comment: Oops :-) Comes from excessive n00bness, I guess. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @corvus Just a demonstration of how useful stacktraces are - a couple minutes of staring at just the code didn't reveal anything obvious, but a few seconds with the stacktrace leads to just the right lines to look at more deeply. Whenever possible, include a stacktrace with a problem description.